# Merge perl hash with HTML::Template param()

Tags: perl

I have a multidimensional hash. Sometimes, when there is only one hash, then I want to send that single hash to a specific HTML::Template file.

I've read that you can combine two hashes like this:

`@hash1{ keys %hash2 } = values %hash2;`

But in my scenario I would like all the keys and values in my hash to be sent to the template file.

What I want to avoid is this:

```
$template->param(
  param1 => $myhash{'param1'},
  param2 => $myhash('param2'),
  paramX => $myhash('paramX'),
  name   => "Bob",
);
```

I want something like this:

```
$template->param(
  { keys %myhash } = values %myhash,
  name => "Bob"
);
```

But I guess that would not work.

Any ideas?

Edit. This code returns error `HTML::Template->param() : You gave me an odd number of parameters to param()!`

```
my %myhash = ( '9343X' => { 'param1' => 'Walter', 'param2' => 'Blue', 'param3' => 513 } );

$items = scalar (keys %myhash);

if ($items == 1) {
  my ($firstkey) = %myhash;
  $template->param(
    $myhash{$firstkey},
    name => "Bob"
  );
}
```

However, if I replace `$myhash{$firstkey}` with `$param1 = $myhash{$firstkey}{'param1'}` it works fine. But I want to avoid specifying each parameter.

Comment: `$template->param(%myhash, name => "Bob");`?

Comment: Thanks. That seems simple. For some reason it is not working for me. I've updated my question with more of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash in list context produces a list of paired key-value scalars.

```perl
$template->param(
  %myhash,
  name => "Bob"
);
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems simple. For some reason it is not working for me. I've updated my question with more of my code.

Comment: You provided a single scalar. You want `%{ $myhash{$firstkey} }`. You could use `( map { %$_ } values( %myhash ) )`